# how to add color, background-color value through variable in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Its my code. How to assign the values for **CSS** through variable and the use same in PyQt5 stylesheet ?

```
    self.label = QLabel("sample")
    self.label.setObjectName("label_1")
    self.label.setStyleSheet(my_stylesheet())

def my_stylesheet():
    return """
    QLabel#label_1{color:red;background-color:blue;}
    """
```

Instead of direct values (like red, blue), assign it in a  variable and how to use it.
For ex :

```
color_1 =red
color_2 = blue
QLabel#label_1{"color:color_1; background-color:color_2;}
```

Comment: Use f-string or `str.format` method eg: `f"{{color: {color_1}; background-color: {color_2};}}"`

Comment: not work for me

Comment: Did you use this? `f"QLabel#label_1{{color: {color_1}; background-color: {color_2};}}"` also in your `color_1 =red` the red should be a string.

Comment: @tckraomuqnt are you asking if you can use a "dynamic" variable reference in the stylesheet, so that everytime the value of that variable changes the stylesheet is updated as well? If that's the case, no, you can't: stylesheets are static strings that are evaluated once they're set.

Comment: hai @Art, Can you request to explain/attach a  minimum code.

Comment: @Bala sorry I didn't get you. Can you clarify your comment?

Comment: @art, Your code not work for me also. So i wnt to know how to implement it ? so request yout to a minimum programme for your code to understand.

Comment: @Bala [here](https://pastebin.com/75XwUjsp)

Comment: @art, wors perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use property where the Qt stylesheet change is applied in the setter:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(
        self, background=QColor("white"), foreground=QColor("black"), parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._background = background
        self._foreground = foreground

        self._change_stylesheet()

    @property
    def background(self):
        return self._background

    @background.setter
    def background(self, color):
        if self._background == color:
            return
        self._background = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    @property
    def foreground(self):
        return self._foreground

    @foreground.setter
    def foreground(self, color):
        if self._foreground == color:
            return
        self._foreground = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    def _change_stylesheet(self):
        qss = "QLabel{color:%s;background-color:%s}" % (
            self.background.name(),
            self.foreground.name(),
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    label = Label()
    label.setText("Qt is awesome!!!")
    label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 40))

    label.background = QColor("red")
    label.foreground = QColor("blue")

    w = QMainWindow()
    w.setCentralWidget(label)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complicated python codes or creating custom classes, you can do something like this:

```
primary_color = '#000000'
secondary_color = '#ffffff'

stylesheet = """
QMainWindow {
    background-color: $primary_color;
}

QDialog {
    background-color: $secondary_color;
}
""".replace('$primary_color', primary_color)\
    .replace('$secondary_color', secondary_color)

self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

First, create variables for any colors you use in your style. Then in your `stylesheet` variable, you can use a string like `$primary_color` instead of your color.
Then at the end, replace this string with the variable that holds your color.

After that, you can set this style as the page stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't give a direct solution to your problem. But it solves your problem, somehow.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

color_red = "color_red"
color_blue = "color_blue"

backcolor_skyblue = "bcolor_skyblue"
backcolor_lightgreen = "bcolor_lightgreen"

class CssSample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Css Stylesheet")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Sample 1 Label")
        self.label_1.setFixedSize(200,50)
        self.label_1.setProperty("color",color_red )
        self.label_1.setProperty("backcolor",backcolor_skyblue)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet(my_stylesheet())

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Sample 2 Label")
        self.label_2.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.label_2.setProperty("color", color_blue)
        self.label_2.setProperty("backcolor",backcolor_lightgreen)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(my_stylesheet())

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

def my_stylesheet():
    
    return """
    QLabel[color = "color_red"]
    { color : red;font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-style: normal; font-size:12pt; font-weight:700; }
    
    QLabel[color = "color_blue"]
    { color : blue;font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-style: normal; font-size:12pt; font-weight:700;}
    
    QLabel[backcolor = "bcolor_skyblue"]
    { background-color : skyblue}
    
    QLabel[backcolor = "bcolor_lightgreen"]
    { background-color : lightgreen}
    
    QLabel{ background-color: @mycolor;}
    
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = CssSample()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```